# image overlay/overlap with css

Tags: android, css, image

I have a Toolbar image (android), then I want to add another small image(question mark image) over this toolbar image. And then when any one click on that small iamge, a new page will show. I know how to show a new page or others. But dont know how to set the small image over the toolbar image. I am very weak with CSS.

So, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use something like

```
.smallImage{
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  display : hidden;
}
```

Then insert an <img /> after the toolbar image. Set its display to block when needed and  play with top and left value to let it appears in the right place.
"relative" here means "position relative to parent".